# Pandas API documentation

Tags: python, pandas

Where do you find complete documentation about the Pandas library?

There's a number of functions like `get_storer()`, `select_as_multiple()`, `select_as_coordinates()` that are not described in the [0.16.2 documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#hdfstore-pytables-hdf5)

I understand a lot of stuff can be done with `dataframes` if you can load them into memory, but my data is prohibitively large so I need to work straight out of the `HDFStore` and need documentation for this part of Pandas.

Comment: i think those are part of the HDF5 library.

Comment: You can always inspect doc strings (where available), e.g. `print(pd.HDFStore.select_as_multiple.__doc__)`.

Comment: Thank you both but especially ajcr for the doc string tip.